# Passing R markdown parameters to a sourced R script

Tags: r, shiny, parameter-passing, r-markdown, environment

I have a Shiny app, in which users can select options that are passed to a parameterised R markdown report.  The Rmd then sources a series of R scripts to extract and summarise data, create plots etc. for the report.

The script I am sourcing to extract the data includes a parameterised SQL query, which inherits values from the R markdown `params` (which in turn are inherited from the Shiny `input`).  However, the whole process stops at this point and I get an error stating that `params` does not exist.

I'm reasonably certain that passing the inputs from Shiny to R markdown params is working fine - so it seems the problem is passing them to the sourced script (note: it is just an R script, not a function).  I'm guessing this has something to do with the environment that the script is accessing when it is sourced (though it uses a database connection generated in a previous chunk in the R markdown without problems) - but beyond that, a bit lost as to how to correct this.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Here is the Shiny app:

```
##########################################
# SHINY APP - USER INTERFACE:

ui = fluidPage (
    selectInput("pathogen", "Enter pathogen of interest:", c("Campylobacter" = "Campylobacter", "Escherichia" = "Escherichia",
                "Salmonella" = "Salmonella", "Shigella" = "Shigella"), selected = "Salmonella" ),

    radioButtons("pkginstall", "Install required packages?",  c("Yes" = "yes", "No" = "no"),selected = "yes"),

    downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
)


##########################################
# SHINY APP - SERVER LOGIC:

#fileInput("download_location","Select File Location"),
server = function(input, output) {
    # Create the output: 
    output$report = downloadHandler(

      filename = paste0("Pathogen Report ", input$pathogen, "_", format(Sys.time(),"%d-%b-%Y %H.%M"), ".html"),

      content = function(file) {

        # Copy the .Rmd to a temporary directory:
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "Pathogen_Report.Rmd")
        file.copy("Pathogen_Report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)


        # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document:
        params <- list(pathogen = input$pathogen, pkginstall = input$pkginstall)

        # Define name of report:
        outname <- paste0("Pathogen Report ", input$pathogen, "_", format(Sys.time(),"%d-%b-%Y %H.%M"), ".html") 

        # Knit the document:
        created_filename <- rmarkdown::render(input = tempReport, 
                          output_file = outname, 
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
                          )
        file.rename(created_filename, file)
      }
    )
  }

##########################################
# SHINY APP - RUN:

# Run app:
shinyApp(ui =ui, server=server)

##################################################################
```

And here is the R markdown YAML header:

```
---
params:
  pathogen: 
    label: "Enter pathogen of interest:" 
    value: Shigella
    input: select
    choices: [Campylobacter, Escherichia, Salmonella, Shigella]
title: "Pathogen Report"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output: 
  phecharts::html_phe:
    includes:
      in_header: phe_logo.html
---
```

And the relevant chunk sourcing the R script:

```
{r, GDW Query, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='hide'}
####################################################################
# QUERY DATABASE AND EXTRACT DATA 

source("Extract_data.R")
```

`Extract_data.R` contains an SQL query in which the pathogen name is supposed to be substituted for that inherited from the R markdown params:

```
# Example SQL to PostgreSQL database:
query <- "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.organism ~ '^@pathogen'"

# Substituting pathogen for pathogen name from R markdown parameters:
query <- gsub("@pathogen", params$pathogen, query)

# Executing the query:
mydata <- data.table(RPostgres::dbGetQuery(conn = dbcon, statement = query))
```

Note that the database connection was already succesfully established by sourcing another script in the R markdown chunk preceding this.

This is the error I get:

```
Quitting from lines 84-88 (Pathogen_Report.Rmd) 

Warning: Error in gsub: object 'params' not found
  [No stack trace available]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the argument `local` in `source` (`?source`).

> `local`  TRUE, FALSE or an environment, determining where the parsed expressions are evaluated. FALSE (the default) corresponds to the user's workspace (the global environment) and TRUE to the environment from which source is called.

When rendering the `Rmd` directly, the `params` are the ones set by default, and you are in the global environment. So this will work:

````
---
params:
  pathogen: 
    label: "Enter pathogen of interest:" 
    value: Shigella
    input: select
    choices: [Campylobacter, Escherichia, Salmonella, Shigella]
  pkginstall:
    value: no
title: "Pathogen Report"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output: html_document
---

```{r GDW Query, echo=TRUE, cache=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='hide'}
####################################################################
# QUERY DATABASE AND EXTRACT DATA 
source(Extract_data.R, local=FALSE) # same as source(Extract_data.R)
````

However, when running the `Rmd` through a `Shiny App` you want to work in the environment that `Shiny` works in, and you want to source the external script as if it was pasted in line (see https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html). The following should work:

````
---
params:
  pathogen: 
    label: "Enter pathogen of interest:" 
    value: Shigella
    input: select
    choices: [Campylobacter, Escherichia, Salmonella, Shigella]
  pkginstall:
    value: no
title: "Pathogen Report"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output: html_document
---

```{r GDW Query, echo=TRUE, cache=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='hide'}
####################################################################
# QUERY DATABASE AND EXTRACT DATA 
source(Extract_data.R, local=TRUE)
````

Comment: this solution works broadly in all containerized Rmarkdown cloud deployments with a nested R-script.   I used it to make a serverless report generator work in GCP Cloud Run. Deserves more than one upvote.